# Valgrind: Deliberately cause segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

This is a *mad-hack*, but I am trying to deliberately cause a segfault at a particular point in execution, so valgrind will give me a stack trace.

If there is a better way to do this please tell me, but I would still be curious to know how to deliberaly cause a segfault, and why my attempt didn't work.

This is my failed attempt:

```
long* ptr = (long *)0xF0000000;
ptr = 10;
```

I thought valgrind should at least pick up on that as a invalid write, even if it's not a segmentation violation. Valgrind says nothing about it.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

Answer accepted, but I still have some up-votes for any suggestions for a more sane way to get a stack trace...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18986351/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you missing a `*` as in `*ptr = 10`? What you have won't compile.

If it does, somehow, that of course won't cause a seg-fault, since you're just assigning a number. Dereferencing might.

Assuming dereferencing null on your OS results in a segfault, the following should do the trick:

```
inline void seg_fault(void)
{
    volatile int *p = reinterpret_cast<volatile int*>(0);
    *p = 0x1337D00D;
}
```

Comment: The * is directly next to the type "long*"

Comment: I still haven't decided which form I prefer - "long* ptr", "long *ptr", "long * ptr"

Comment: How did that compile, then? What compiler are you using?

Comment: C Pointer Style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why/378389#378389

Answer (score 7):

Just call `abort()`. It's not a segfault but it should generate a core dump.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for mentioning the obvious but why not use gdb with a breakbpoint and then use backtrace?

```
(gdb) b somewhere
(gdb) r
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not experienced enough on gdb to know how. :)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers you can just call `abort()` if you want to abnormally terminate your program entirely, or `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV)` if it has to be a segmentation fault.  This will generate a core file that you can use with gdb to get a stack trace or debug even if you are not running under valgrind.

Using a valgrind [client request](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.clientreq) you can also have valgrind dump a stack trace with your own custom message and then continue executing.  The client request does nothing when the program is not running under valgrind.

```
#include <valgrind/valgrind.h>
...
VALGRIND_PRINTF_BACKTRACE("Encountered the foobar problem, x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you on x86? If so then there is actually an opcode in the CPU that means "invoke whatever debugger may be attached". This is opcode `CC`, or more commonly called `int 3`. Easiest way to trigger it is with inline assembly:

```
inline void debugger_halt(void)
{
#ifdef MSVC
   __asm int 3;
#elif defined(GCC)
   asm("int 3");
#else
#pragma error Well, you'll have to figure out how to do inline assembly 
              in your compiler
#endif
}
```

MSVC also supports `__debugbreak()` which is a hardware break in unmanaged code and an MSIL "break" in managed code.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to send sig SEGV (11) to the process to force a core dump?

Comment: Generally, you can't know the exact point during execution (upon which you want to send SIGSEGV) from outside the process.

Comment: The process can send SIGSEGV to itself: `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);`