# Why there is no throw or sigsegv while accessing empty std::optional?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, segmentation-fault, stdoptional

The example:

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    optional<int> t{}; // nullopt (empty) by default

    cout << *t << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Actually this program prints some int (uninitialized value of type `int`).
Also, libcxx uses assert-check for accessing non-engaged value.

Why the Standard does not require throwing or sigsegv here?

Comment: The same reason as for `std::vector::operator[]`

Comment: @JonathanWakely `std::vector::operator[]` can sigsegv, but optional will never sigsegv.

Comment: "sigsegv" isn't part of the C++ standard. The consistent theme here is "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @vladon They are both undefined behavior, they both might sigsegv, they might both throw, they might both do anything at all.

Comment: SIGSEGV is the signal raised when you access memory outside your address space, a disengaged `optional` object is obviously not outside your address space, it just doesn't contain an initialized value. Why should it cause a segfault?

Comment: @JonathanWakely "not outside your address space" - it's a detail of implementation. I'm asking why standard does not require anything.

Comment: Requiring a hard error is a trade-off between performance and usability. Requiring a well defined error requires that the implementation performs a check. When faced with these dilemmas, c++ usually goes with the decision that avoids imposing overhead.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour does not mandate a specific result. *Anything* can happen. Just don't write bugs is the only advice that can be given.

Comment: If it is required to throw, `t.value()` should be used. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why the Standard does not require throwing or sigsegv here?

Because requiring some particular behaviour implicitly imposes the requirement to add a branch to check whether that behaviour - be it throwing or something else - should occur.

By specifying that the behaviour is undefined, the standard allows the implementation to *not* check whether optional is empty upon every indirection. Branching the execution is potentially slower than not branching.

Rather than mandating safety, the committee let the standard library implementers to choose performance (and simplicity). The implementation that you tested seems to have chosen to not throw an exception or otherwise inform you of the mistake.

Comment: _"The committee chose performance over safety."_ The committee chose to leave it up to the std::lib implementation to decide, and the implementation might choose performance in some configurations and safe in others (e.g. when assertions are enabled).

Comment: It's more that the committee chooses not the impose overhead if the same result can be achieved by the user with a manual test of their own if they desire it. It's not about letting the implementation choose what solution they want to go with, implementers can add whatever safety checks they want provided it doesn't violate any other part of the standard (like complexity requirements (but even then some do for debug builds)).

Answer (score 8):

C++ embraces the idea of undefined behavior.

Not all C++ operations have behavior defined by the standard.  This permits compilers to assume they never happen, and can result in much faster code in many cases.

Here, by leaving the result of using a `std::optional` that is unengaged undefined, it the cost of accessing data stored in a `std::optional` is the same as the cost of accessing data not stored in a `std::optional`.  The only costs are the extra room required, and you as a programmer promising to keep track of if it is engaged or not.

Now compilers are free to insert checks there, and some do in debug builds.

Note that usually C++ `std` library types include *safe* and *unsafe* methods for accessing data.

The fact that invalid pointers sometimes result in a sigsev is because most OS's protect addresses around 0 and crash programs that access it.  This is because this was low cost, and it catches a bunch of bad behavior from many assembly, C and C++ programs.

If you want optional to throw when empty, use `.value()`.  If you don't, use `operator*`.  If you want a default value if one isn't there, use `.value_or`.

Comment: Not just around address 0. Whenever you cross a page boundary you'll usually get a fault if the page is not mapped. Not fatal if the page is in your address space (the OS will just map it in) but otherwise fatal.

Comment: @jesp sure, but barring garbage pointer data, pointee that once pointed somewhere don't give pagefaults usually.

Answer (score 6):

Because it is undefined behavior, section [[optional.observe]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.observe#5) says:

> Requires: *this contains a value.

and violating a requires clause is undefined behavior, from [[res.on.required#1]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.required#1) which is under  [Library-wide requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/requirements):

> Violation of any preconditions specified in a function's Requires: element results in undefined behavior unless the function's Throws: element specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated.

So you have no expecation as to the result. From the definition of [undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined):

> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements

Requiring the implementation to check would be a cost and not all users would want to take that cost. So this becomes a quality of implementation issue. An implementation is free to performing checks in different modes of operation for example when assertions are enabled.

The user has the option of taking the cost themselves via [has_value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) or [value_or](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or). If the user wants an operation that can throw they can use [value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value).

Note that [sigsegv, segfaults etc... are an implementation defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986406/1708801).